# How to label image without using bounding box?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, bounding-box, transfer-learning

I'm trying to create custom dataset using my own images. This images I cropped from logs data such as below:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x0oWiVZ9KOw5P0gIMxQNxO-ajdrGy7Te

I want it to be able to detect the high vibration such as below:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tUjthjGG1c23kTCQZOgedcsx99R_a_z3

I have around 300 image of the High Vibration in one folder. the picture is like below:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IG_-wRJxe-_TOYfSxHjRq5UBWMn9mO1k

I wanted to do exactly like https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9. IN this example image dataset was hand-labeled manually with LabelImg.

However I don't see why I need to draw box for images that only have one object in it and can have the frame of the image as the bounding box.

Please advice how I can create data set and processing the images without manually drawing the bounding box (since the images consist of one object), and how to draw bounding boxes in batch for image that contain one object(i.e. having the frame of the image as the bounding box)?

Comment: Someone already tried using the cropped images to train the object detection model and it seems not to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093955/tensorflow-object-detection-api-using-image-crops-as-training-dataset

Comment: Thanks! Apparently object classification and object detection need different data set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do 'image classification' as opposed to 'object detection' -- it may be easier to make a script that generates xml files, containing the image's width and height as bounding box dimensions, as opposed to using labelImg.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).